# String to ascii function

Tags: c++, ascii

I actually wrote a function to convert string into ascii values.
However I managed to confuse my self and don't understand why my own code works.

here it is:

```
void convertToString()
{
    char redo;
    int letter;
    int length;
    do {
        cout<< "How long is your word \n";
        cin >> length;

        cout << "Type in the letter values \n";

        for (int x = 0; x < length; x++) {
            cin >> letter;
            cout << char (letter);
        }

        cout << "\n To enter another word hit R" << endl;
        cin >> redo;

    } while (redo == 'R');
}
```

In the terminal I can type in all the ASCII values I want with out changing line, however I though this would cause a problem, anyways my question is, is hitting the enter button the same as hitting space? if not i dont understand how my code is able to print out the chars since i write it all in one line...Does it assign the interger "letter" a new value everytime there is a space?

Please help/explain

Comment: `is hitting the enter button the same as hitting space?` In this particular program, yes. `ostream::operator>>(int&)` would skip all the whitespace (whether spaces, tabs or end-of-lines) first thing, before processing non-whitespace characters. It would stop reading at the first non-digit (again, that could be a space or end-of-line, among others).

Comment: Thank you very much! I think i understand now! So its actually printing the first char before reading the next correct?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "it" in your statement. `operator>>` certainly doesn't print anything, before or after.

Answer (score 0):

This is to expand a bit on what Igor said in his comment and to give a little example.

As Igor said, `istream::operator>>(&int)` will read non-whitespace. This means for each call on the operator, it scans along the input stream (what you typed in) for non-whitespace and reads until the next whitespace again. The next call will pick up where you left off. So, entering a space or a newline is exactly the same for this situation where you're taking in an int.

You can verify this with a simple bit of code that scans until EOF:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    int number;
    while (std::cin >> number)
    {
        std::cout << number << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This will wait for user entry to be complete (pressing enter), but print a new line for each integer in your input as separated by whitespace. So "1 2 3 4" will print each of those numbers on separate lines, regardless of if you separate them with spaces, tabs, or newlines.